# Pull requestのrebase

Tags: git, github

GitHubの初心者の質問です．

`develop`ブランチからpull-requestを出したら、`hotfix/3.3.2`で`rebase`を要求されました．
こういう場合、どのように処理すれば良いのでしょうか？大変すみませんが教えてください．

https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/pull/3287#pullrequestreview-234301759

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git remote -v` コマンド実行結果が次のような状態であると仮定して話を進めます:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/ToshihikoMakita/dita-ot.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ToshihikoMakita/dita-ot.git (push)
```

---

プルリクしている(今回の修正をコミットしている)ブランチ `develop` を checkout します:

```
git checkout develop
```

本家リモートリポジトリを `upstream` という名前で追加します:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot.git
```

この結果、 `git remote -v` の結果は次のように変わります:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/ToshihikoMakita/dita-ot.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ToshihikoMakita/dita-ot.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot.git (push)
```

`upstream` リモートリポジトリをローカルへ取り込みます:

```
git fetch upstream
```

これでプルリク先(=本来の分岐元)のブランチ `hotfix/3.3.2` がローカルで参照できるようになりました。
rebaseしてここから分岐したように修正します:

```
git rebase -i -p upstream/hotfix/3.3.2
```

次に示す2つのコミットが表示されると思います。このうち、プルリクしたいコミット以外を消します。すなわち、1行目を削除し2行目だけ残します。

```
pick 163090de3 Merge tag '3.3.1' into develop
pick 02345b2f3 Use OASIS namspace for generating catalog-dita.xml
```

編集が完了したら保存して閉じます。

続いてこのrebaseしたブランチをあなたのリモートリポジトリ `origin` に force push します:

```
git push -f origin HEAD
```

以上です。
pull request が更新されているはずです。
(pull request に `force-pushed` ログが残ります。)

---

[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54790/pull-request%E3%81%AErebase/54811?noredirect=1#comment58685_54811)を書かれた時点でのリポジトリを参照しました。おそらく想定していないコミットが含まれています。
`git log --graph upstream/hotfix/3.3.2..origin/develop` コマンドで履歴を確認してみてください。

プルリクエストを出したいコミットは
https://github.com/ToshihikoMakita/dita-ot/commit/4496fc355f377aac560640f9fa2417b0eb3c1998
だけではないでしょうか。
`develop`ブランチにはそれ以外のコミットも含まれてしまっています。

プルリクエストしたいのは上記のコミットだけだ、という私の想定が正しいのであれば

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard 4496fc355f377aac560640f9fa2417b0eb3c1998
git push -f origin HEAD
```

を実行すれば想定通りのプルリクエストになります。

> DCOでエラーが付いた状態です．

というのは、プルリクエストに
https://github.com/ToshihikoMakita/dita-ot/commit/60fd9916c354ab2181a84adc65d0c26c03f9d2af
などが含まれているからでしょう。

正常なプルリクエストになったのであれば、[このプルリクエストページ](https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/pull/3287)から他の方のコミット履歴は消えるはずです。

Comment: 初心者なので本質を外しているかもしれません．私は質問に示したDITA-OTのURLのリポジトリのメンバーではありません．このため、GitHubの自分のアカウントのリポジトリにcloneして、これをローカルにチェックアウトして作業をしました．hotfix/3.3.2は私が自分のGitHubのリポジトリにcloneした後に本家で作成されたものです．このような場合はどのように処理すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 前提を見直して回答を更新しました。 `git remote -v` の結果が本文に記載したものと異なる場合は実際の出力をお知らせください。

Comment: 記載していただいたものに加え、`upstream        https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot.git (fetch)`
`upstream        https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot.git (push)` が表示されている状態です．

Comment: 回答を更新しました。 `git fetch upstream` 以降の手順を実施すれば良いでしょう。

Comment: ご指摘のように実行しOKと思うのですが、Signed-off-by:を入れているのにDCOでエラーが付いた状態です．回答のacceptはもうしばらくお待ちください．

Comment: ご指摘通りでした．DCOのチェックを通りました！